# Load an url only one time

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a table of url I want to load, the table can have one or more time an url.

For example, a table with three values : url1, url2 url1.

So, after, I load an url, an extract one of his html piece(for example a ).

I have this :

```
    HtmlPage page=null;


for (int i = 0; i < tableUrlSource.length; i++) {
try {
                page = webClient.getPage(tabUrlSource[i]);
                List<HtmlElement> nbElements = (List<HtmlElement>) page.getByXPath(tabXpathSource[i]);
                if (null != nbElements && !nbElements.isEmpty()) {
                    htmlResult = nbElements.get(0).asText();

    }

...
```

But this is not the more efficient, because it will load url1 two times and url one time.
So it will like there is three url to load, and then, make the treatment longer.

How can I load an url only one time and keep the same final result?

I hope my english is clear, so as my question.

Regards.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Keppil answered is correct but  you would have to use the Set in place of  tabUrlSource[i] rather than for `Set<HtmlElement>`

EDIT:
Okay what is the content of tabUrlSource[i]?Is it of type URL or custom?
This is how it would look like if it is URL

```
  Set <URL>uniqueURLs = new HashSet <URL>();

  for (int i = 0; i < tableUrlSource.length; i++) { 
  uniqueURLs.add(tableUrlSource[i])
  }
```

And then iterate over this Set instead of tableUrlSource array like this

```
  for(Iterator itr = uniqueURLs.iterator(); itr.hasNext();  ){
   page = webClient.getPage((URL)itr.next());
    .............
    .............
```

Continue the rest of the code

Also you said you are using index 'i' to associate url and xpath. Will that xpath be same for same url? If so you can use HashMap instead with key as URL and value as xpath so that duplicate keys will be overridden. Then you can iterate over this hashmap keys to get the 'page' and use the 'value' for to fetch HTMLELEMENT

If they are not same you can still use a HashSet like this

```
  Set <URL>uniqueURLs = new HashSet <URL>();
      HtmlPage page=null;


   for (int i = 0; i < tableUrlSource.length; i++) {
   try {    
            if(uniqueURLs.contains(tabUrlSource[i]) continue;
            else
             uniqueURLs.add( tabUrlSource[i] );
            page = webClient.getPage(tabUrlSource[i]);
            List<HtmlElement> nbElements = (List<HtmlElement>) 
            page.getByXPath(tabXpathSource[i]);
            if (null != nbElements && !nbElements.isEmpty()) {
                htmlResult = nbElements.get(0).asText();

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yeah, but if you know this way, can you explain more? No need to change for the htmlelement, but if you can explain for the url ^^

Comment: Than you, i will try this.
_italic_Okay what is the content of tabUrlSource[i]?Is it of type URL or custom? This is how it would look like if it is URL_italic_
It's a table of string, but your code seems good anymway. Thank you

Comment: I tried the second solution; did'nt work. For the link url, xpath, for example I have taburl and tabxpath : url1 xpatha / url2 xpathb / url1 xpathc. So it need to know, which xpath go with which url.

Comment: So that xpath tabs vary for same URL? And if you want to avoid calling webClient.getPage for same URL you could use prepopulated HashMap instead with 'key' as URL and value as array of xpaths and then iterate over this keyset load each page and load the xpaths corresponding to this URL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Set<HtmlElement>` instead of a `List`. This will remove duplicates automatically.

This of course is dependant on the fact that `HtmlElement`s are comparable. If they aren't, you could instead add all the URLs to a `Set<String>` and then iterate over that.

***Update***

To clarify the second part:

A [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is declared like this in the Javadocs:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.

In other words, to ensure that there are no duplicates, it relies on the elements being comparable via the `equals()` method. If `HtmlElement` hasn't overridden this method, the `Set` will just use the `Object.equals()` method, which just compares object references instead of the actual data in the `HtmlElements`.

However, `String` has overridden the `equals()` method, and you can therefor be certain that duplicate `String`s will be removed from a `Set<String>`.

Comment: "You could use a Set<HtmlElement> instead of a List. This will remove duplicates automatically. " No need to modify this.
Can you explain more for the second part?

Comment: @Jean: Updated with a more thorough explanation.

Comment: not sure if it's possible with my code; I have a table of url, and a table of xpath associate. And both use i to be associate. Using a loop for. The table need to have all url, even duplicates, and i don't see, how to apply your method.I'm confuse. Add more code.